# What is the difference between a built-in font and a third-party font to Java?

Tags: java, macos, swing, fonts, jlabel

Trying to figure out what may be a bug in the code for MultiLineLabel found here: http://samuelsjoberg.com/archive/2009/10/multiline-labels-in-swing

Essentially, that sample will run just fine with, say, Arial. But if I install a custom font to my Mac, like ITCKorinna-Bold, it still renders the MultiLineLabel, but it doesn't add any linebreaks, so 
"This is a 
long line." becomes "This is ..."

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
Hot-link to the Font on the net.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux with OpenJDK 7 update 19 it works just fine. You haven't supplied your code so its kind of hard for us to see if there might be anything wrong with that.

When I modify the example to use Roboto the line breaks work as expected.

I don't know which Java runtime you are using but if you are using the one supplied by Apple there might be a difference in the values returned by the FontMetrics object (since the Apple Java runtime does font rendering different then for example OpenJDK on Linux). I would suggest trying OpenJDK and see if that makes a difference or run your app on a different platform and see if that makes a difference.

```
    Font robotoFont = null;
    try {
        robotoFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("/usr/share/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Black.ttf"));
        robotoFont = robotoFont.deriveFont(14f);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Using the MultiLineLabel class.
    final MultiLineLabel mLabel = new MultiLineLabel(
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
                    + "Phasellus non sapien quam. Fusce posuere, nisl "
                    + "vitae tristique volutpat, augue erat faucibus nisl, "
                    + "nec venenatis metus sem vel enim. Cras in libero "
                    + "sapien, vitae euismod neque. Proin hendrerit, odio "
                    + "et faucibus suscipit, eros tellus blandit justo, "
                    + "ac cursus risus elit ut risus.");
    mLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    mLabel.setFont(robotoFont);
```

[image]